# How can I create an interface when my object has an array inside of it?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object in Javascript that I want to be able to pass around:

```
var a = 
{
 "city":null,
 "text":"x",
 "cities":[{ "locId":1,     // int
             "type":null,   // null or string
             "state":false, // true or false
             "text":"x"},
            {"locId":2,
             "type":null,
             "state":false,
             "text":"x"}
           ]
}
```

I started to learn about typescript. Can someone tell me how can I make an interface to model this object. Also where can I put that.  I read about having a global.d.ts file.  Is that where interfaces are usually stored or would it be a global.ts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There would be one interface for the first object stored in a variable, let's call it `ISomething`. Then there would be an interface for the city `ICity`.

```
interface ISomething{
    city: ICity;
    text: string;
    cities: ICity[];
}

interface ICity {
    locId: number;
    type: string;
    state: boolean;
    text: string;
}
```

You can store these in standard `.ts` file. I would put interfaces to `d.ts` files only in case you are creating interface for code which is not yours.

Since *typescript* supports modules, I would put such interfaces to a module rather then to a global scope.